# Identify Japanese instrumental song

Tags: identify-this-song, japan

I'm trying to find out the title of a supposedly Japanese song, since whenever I hear that tune on TV, they're talking about Japan. I've been trying with Shazam and SoundHound, but in vain.

I have made a short recording of the song and uploaded it here: https://vocaroo.com/7DN21Vlc38T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up finding it by myself: it's the [theme song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LF9_9MZyQGo) of ["Merry Christmas, Mr. Lawrence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merry_Christmas,_Mr._Lawrence), composed by [Ryuichi Sakamoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryuichi_Sakamoto). The part that I recorded starts at [0:55](https://youtu.be/LF9_9MZyQGo?t=55).